# Converting National Bridge Inventory(NBI) ASCII file to shapefile

Tags: arcgis-desktop, ascii

I have downloaded the NBI ascii file data from http://www.fhwa.dot.gov/bridge/nbi/ascii.cfm. Now I am not able to convert it into a shapefile. The ASCII file has a latitude longitude column. I understand that it can be imported in a GIS software using X,Y values. But I am not able to make out whether the latitude longitude is in DMS or decimal degrees.

I am posting a sample here.

Sample Latitude: 40454200
Sample Longitude: 122190700

If there is any other way of converting it, I would like to know.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One row is too small a sample to be conclusive, but it certainly appears to be DMS (specifically, dDDMMSSHH, with an implied west longitude). You can confirm this by scanning the file and looking for a value of 60 or larger in any of the MM or SS elements. If it is in this format, then conversion to decimal degrees is as simple as parsing out the minutes  and hundredths of seconds, and dividing them by 60 and 360000 (respectively), and adding those to the degrees.  Don't forget to apply negation to the longitude.

You could also read the [documentation](http://www.fhwa.dot.gov/bridge/mtguide.pdf), which states that the values are degrees, minutes, and hundredths of seconds (pages 19 & 20).

Comment: I also use these data. Could you provide a direct link to the documentation? [The schema description located here](https://www.fhwa.dot.gov/bridge/nbi/format.cfm) has no such information.

Comment: The first line of text in the link provided by the OP is "Recording and Coding Guide for the Structure Inventory and Appraisal of the Nations Bridges (pdf, 0.8 Mb)".  "Coding Guide" should be a magical phrase for this sort of search.

Answer (score 6):

I have used NBI data several times, once in [this article](http://www.esri.com/news/arcuser/0708/files/tappingpython.pdf) I wrote for ArcUser years ago, and a couple of times in training sessions. Here's a function that will parse the space-delimited version of NBI and return you a list of some of the bits (haven't used it in a while, but should get you going). Also, here are [the NBI data docs](https://www.fhwa.dot.gov/bridge/mtguide.pdf).

```python
def ParseNbiFile(file_path):
    """ Parses NBI bridge file and return what we want in a list """
    # Open the text file, read it into memory
    data = open(file_path).read().splitlines()
    # Define a new, empty list object
    l = []
    # Iterate through the lines of the file, slice up the line by index
    #   position of each data column
    ln = 0
    for line in data:
    latDMS = line[129:137] 
    lonDMS = line[137:146]
    # Only process rows with valid lat/lon values
    if len(latDMS.strip()) > 0 and int(lonDMS.strip()) > 0:
        latDeg = latDMS[0:2] 
        #print latDeg
        latMin = latDMS[2:4]  
        #print latMin
        latSec = latDMS[4:6]+'.'+latDMS[6:8]  
        #print latSec
        latDD = str(int(latDeg)+(float(latMin)/60)+(float(latSec)/3600)) 
        lonDeg = lonDMS[0:3]
        #print lonDeg
        lonMin = lonDMS[3:5] 
        #print lonMin
        lonSec = lonDMS[5:7]+'.'+lonDMS[7:9]  
        #print lonSec
        lonDD = str('-'+str(int(lonDeg)+(float(lonMin)/60)+float(lonSec)/3600)) 
        yearBuilt = line[156:160]  
        strucNum = line[4:18]
        #print '\n' + str(strucNum)
        facility = line[62:80]
        # Add our line to list l
        # Do string formatting to lat/long to only display 5 decimal points
        l.extend([[strucNum, facility, ('%.5f' % float(latDD)), ('%.5f' % float(lonDD)), yearBuilt]])
    return l
```

Answer (score -1):

If bridges are identified, you could navigate to one of them with Google Earth or another online map/satellite resource such as http://itouchmap.com/latlong.html that lets you navigate somewhere and obtain its lat/lon.  Note the actual values in both decimal and dms, then figure out what they're giving you.

I generally use MS Word and MS Excel to whip text stuff into what I need.